# Jquery-style buttonset from UL?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm currently theming a site, and the navigation is in list format:

```
<ul> <li>nav1</li> <li>nav2</li> ... </ul>
```

I'd like to turn the list into a buttonset with rounded corners only on the outside.

ASCII-art approximation:

```
( nav 1 | nav 2 | nav 3 | nav 4 )
```

There's a great example in JQuery-UI, but it's designed for radio buttons instead of list items. I tried making the changes myself, but IE doesn't recognize :last-child so I couldn't get the right corners rounded.

Any tips/suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the markup would look like this:

```
<ul>
  <li class="first">button1</li>
  <li class="second">button2</li>
  <li>button3</li>
  <li class="last">button4</li>
</ul>
```

the CSS for this is:

```
ul {margin:0px;padding:0px;list-style-type:none;}
ul li {margin:0px;padding:0px 5px;border:1px solid #333;}
ul li.first {border-top-left-radius: 100px;border-bottom-left-radius: 100px;border-right:0px;}
ul li.last {border-top-right-radius: 100px;border-bottom-right-radius: 100px;border-left:0px;}
ul li.second {border-right:0px;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use a border-radius on the ul itself.

http://jsfiddle.net/T4cRS/

Should really be using the HTML5 `<nav>` tag if you're using `<!doctype html>`